# Python : UDP Socket How to Waiting Client Side Reply Bytes String

Tags: python, c, udp, client-server

```
import socketserver
import struct
from collections import namedtuple

class MyUDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()
        socket = self.request[1]
        if len(data) >= 34:
            format_ = "6shhih50s2s"
            MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct", "sMark nPackLen nFlag nGisIp nPort sData sEnd")
            tuple_to_send = MyStruct(sMark="\r\n{}".format("*KW").encode("ascii"), 
                     nPackLen=struct.calcsize(format_),
                     nFlag=0x0002,
                     nGisIp=0,
                     nPort=0,
                     sData= "*KW,AA05954122,015,080756,#".encode("ascii"),
                     sEnd="\r\n".encode("ascii"))
            string_to_send = struct.pack(format_, *tuple_to_send._asdict().values())
            socket.sendto(string_to_send, self.client_address)
            print('waiting Reply Bytes String from client..') //how to get the reply bytes  string from Client side?
if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "", 6903
    server = socketserver.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), MyUDPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

**Step 1**:Server receive GPS device bytes string.and will get a dynamic IP address

**Step 2**:when server are get the client dynamic IP already,Server will send a command to client side(GPS Device).

**Step 3**:Client Side will sending back a bytes string,but i have no idea how to capture the reply bytes string on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if server replies to the IP Address and port of the Sender

```
print('waiting Reply Bytes String from client..') //how to get the reply bytes  string from Client side?
bytes = socket.recvfrom(1024);
```